# Replace all non-supported chars with a space

Tags: c#, .net, string

I need to accomplish following. I have list of allowed chars (this is for QB [Issues with special characters in QBO API v3 .NET SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693578/issues-with-special-characters-in-qbo-api-v3-net-sdk))

```
var goodChars = "ABCD...abcd...~_-...";

void string Sanitize(string input)
{
    // TODO: Need to take input and replace all chars not included in "goodChars" with a space
}
```

I know how to find bad chars with RegEx, but this is like backwards, I don't need to look at matches. I need to look at what is not matching and replace only those.

Comment: Did you look at [Regex.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2) ? Perhaps even something as brute as `^[ABCD...abcd...~_-...]` as a pattern? A lot of those characters can be replaced by character classes to make the pattern smaller, eg `\d` can replace `0` to `9`. `A-Za-z` will cover english letters

Comment: What do you want to do with "bad" characters? Remove them entirely? `Regex.Replace(input,pattern,"")` will work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos *"// TODO: Need to … replace all chars not included in "goodChars" with a space"*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string Sanitize(string input)
{
    return new string(input.Select(x => goodChars.Contains(x)?x:' ').ToArray());
}
```

And as **vc 74** suggests, its better to have an `HashSet<char>` of goodChars instead of a string for faster look ups

Comment: @vc74 yes, of course, I was actually focusing on my code part. but its good to mention it in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_) with a negative pattern

```
const string pattern = "[^A-Za-z~_-]";

var regex = new Regex(pattern);
string sanitized = regex.Replace(input, " ");
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mMujcg)

Note that if this code is used frequently, you can store the regex in a static member to avoid recreating (and recompiling) for each invocation.